# how to connect 2 computers using console cable

Tags: networking, rs232, rj-45

I know this is a weird question, however, I have a **console (rollover) cable** - the one used to connect to network devices' console port (e.g. cisco switches).

I'd like to know if it's possible to use this cable in order to **connect 2 regular PCs** (Windows) and have them communicate over this cable.

Comment: Do you have serial ports available on both computers? Are you prepared to get two RJ45-DB9 convertors and rewire them? What sort of communication are you hoping for?

Comment: Andrew has a point. It's basically a no unless you convert the the rj45 end to a db9 and effectively make the cable serial to serial. Then, you're in business.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I have a serial port on one end and an ethernet port on the other end. Isn't it possible to get a terminal connection going **without** any extra hardware? I mean, when I connect with this cable to a console port I get a terminal. Can't I emulate something similar on my PC?

Comment: No, an Ethernet port cannot perform RS-232 communication. The socket fits the RJ45 plug which happens to be on the end of the Cisco serial port cable, but electrically and protocol-wise they are completely different.

Comment: ***BE VERY CAREFUL*** RS232 uses *much* higher voltages, plugging the adapter you have into an Ethernet port could damage the attached circuitry irreparably.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, you indicated that you wish to connect a serial port to an Ethernet port using only a cable wired for serial communication which happens to use RJ45 connectors (technically 8P8C connectors in this context) instead of DB9 (or DB25) connectors.

An Ethernet port cannot perform RS-232 communication. The socket fits the 8P8C plug which happens to be on the end of the Cisco serial port cable, but electrically and protocol-wise they are completely different.

So the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 1):

They can communicate with the proper adapter, but probably not the way you are envisioning.  As mentioned in the comments, the RJ45 connector on your cable is not connected the same as an Ethernet RJ45 connector.  This would be considered a null-modem connection.  You will need the appropriate [DB9-to-RJ45](http://www.usconverters.com/db9-rj45-adapter) modular connector to get standard connections on both ends.  Next, you will probably need some [USB to RS-232 adapters](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/178-5671434-2041043?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=USB+to+RS-232+adapters) unless your computer still has built-in COM ports.  Even still, you will only be able to communicate using RS-232 serial communications.  You would need some sort of terminal emulator software on both computers.

IP-based programs actually can communicate over these cables using the good old 1988 technology of [SLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol) or its replacement, [PPP](https://mikebeach.org/2012/08/30/installing-and-configuring-a-ppp-null-modem-connection-on-windows-7/).  This used to be a fairly common way to provide networking to simpler equipment, back when NICs were expensive.

Due to the limits of RS-232 serial connections, be aware that your maximum throughput will literally be about 10,000 times slower than a gigabit Ethernet crossover cable.

So, it *can* be done, but it probably *shouldn't* be done.